# Joda time with EclipseLink and Postgres makes time disappear from DateTime

Tags: postgresql, datetime, jpa, eclipselink, jodatime

I have the following Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Deal { 
    @Column(nullable = false, insertable = false, columnDefinition = "timestamp default current_timestamp")
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn;
    @Column(nullable = false, insertable = false, columnDefinition = "timestamp default current_timestamp")
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Convert(converter = DateTimeConverter.class)
    private DateTime updatedOn;
    // rest of the fields

    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public DateTime getUpdatedOn() {
        return updatedOn;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void onCreate() {
        this.updatedOn = new DateTime();
        this.createdOn = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void onUpdate() {
        this.updatedOn = new DateTime();
    }
    // etc etc..
}
```

The DateTimeConverter.java:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class DateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<DateTime, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(DateTime dateTime) {
        return dateTime == null ? null : new Date(dateTime.getMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : new DateTime(date);
    }
}
```

As you can see these are just logging related fields, nothing special. The reason that they are different (one being java.util.Date, other being joda.DateTime) is to show the error JodaTime is producing

In my postgres database I have this instance (other columns omitted for simplicity):

```
id |        createdon           |      updatedon
1  | 2014-06-10 15:44:28.233027 | 2014-06-10 15:44:28.233027
```

As you can see the timestamp is stored properly.

The problem is that createdOn is fetched properly from database, but updatedOn loses it's time part completely for no apparent reason.

After I fetched some instances, these 2 values look like this in the debugger:

- ***createdOn***: Tue Jun 10 16:44:44 CEST 2014
- ***updatedOn***: 2014-06-10T00:00:00.000+02:00

Funny thing is, the time value is already lost even in the *convertToEntityAttribute* method in the *DateTimeConverter* class:

- ***date***: 2014-06-10

**EDIT**: 
For clarity, my goal is to use joda DateTime objects instead of regular Date objects because they are easier to work with in general. As it seems, they fail to store the database values properly for some reason.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of a `java.util.Date`

Comment: My goal is to deal with joda DateTime objects when I'm working with Entities. Maybe this was not clear when I wrote the question.